# I using this query it's run but only show the particular date column

Tags: mysql

after remaining column can't show please give me the all column can be show them how to write

select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d') from tablename

Answer (score 0):

Use (*) to get all

select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d'),* from tablename